# what is the best way to print all the values of the fields in a java class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class called Product with some fields.
I want to print all the values for a product object.

```
Class Product{

 String code;
 String description;

}

Product p = new product();
p.setCode("C");
p.setDescription("desc");
```

I want to print values of product instances ex

```
Code:C Description:Desc.
```

I have around 100 classes with lot of fields in all the classes.What is the best way.

Comment: I often try to create a decent `toString()` override for just this sort of thing.

Comment: You can try to use reflection for this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"try to create a decent `toString()`"* Bah!  I go 'indecent' all the way with my `toString()` implementations.  No net nanny, no censorship, none of this politically correct rubbish, no bounds and no limits.  ;)

Comment: I have around 200 classes,writing toString() method for each of the classes does not look good to me.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to override the toString() method in java.lang.Object.

If you use Eclipse, you can autogenerate a toString method that does what you want. Here's a good example of how to do that:

http://idiot2genius.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/eclipse-generate-java-tostring-method-quickly/

There's a very useful class in the Apache Commons Lang project that you might find helpful as well:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to build the string by hand, or manage changes manually, you might consider something like the [Commons Lang `ReflectionToStringBuilder.reflectionToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) method, also available through the `ToStringBuilder` class.